# Save specific fields with elasticsearch-model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-model

I'm using elasticsearch-model gem in a Rails 4 project to store my Users in MySQL and Elasticsearch. In my project, the Elasticsearch part is used to find people with some of the MySQL fields like geo_point, birthdate, gender, etc... But not every fields I've in MySQL "users" table are useful for user's search.

So, I'd like to store ALL users fields in MySQL and only fields needed for user's search in Elasticsearch.

To store only required fields on create, I've overrided the method 'as_indexed_json' and used :

```
as_json(only: ['id', 'gender', 'location']
```

On create, things work great. But when I'm updating a user with fields that should be saved in MySQL only, it adds it to Elasticsearch anyway.

For instance, my User model have "id", "gender", "is_premium", "status", "created_at", "birthdate", "location".
In Elasticsearch I'd like to save only "id", "gender", "birthdate", "location"

How can I do this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with elasticsearch-rails (see [github](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/issues/37)).

In a nutshell the default update callback calls `update_document` which doesn't use `as_indexed_json`: it uses `ActiveModel::Dirty` to only send the changed columns.

You can fix this either by overriding the `update_document` method so that it only includes what you want, or by changing what the callback does, for example

```
after_commit on: [:create, :update] do
  index_document
end

after_commit on: [:destroy] do
  delete_document
end
```

instead of using the default callbacks module will result in `index_document` being used, which always does a 'dumb' full update rather than trying to only send the deltas.

Comment: I tried to override update_document and tried to change the callback, but nothing change : the whole document is indexed.
Here's a gist for more informations : [GIST](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-besnard/4ac9126be9476268a981)

Comment: you need to stop include ::Callbacks once you've used after_commit to add your own

Comment: I did think that es used the implementation of update_document from your class it was available though